# Is there an adverb for "example"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Such as here

> With a degree in humanities, you can "examply" be a museum curator,
>   librarian, or teacher.

You have to assume those are the only choices listed, but not the only ones available. They are just example jobs.  So what is an adverb I can use where the quotation marks are?  (since examply isn't a word)

Comment: The usual way of saying this would be "you can, *for example*, be a museum curator" etc. Is there a reason that structure won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on @1006a's comment, you could use any of the following:

> With a degree in humanities, you can be, for example, a museum
>   curator, librarian, or teacher.
>
> With a degree in humanities, you can be, e.g., a museum curator,
>   librarian, or teacher.
>
> With a degree in humanities, you can be a museum curator, librarian,
>   teacher, or pursue any number of other occupations.

Other possible occupations include lawyer, philosopher, and writer. I wouldn't sell the humanities short, not that you are.

There is not a single-word adverb that I am aware of  that conveys the meaning you're seeking.